how i do organigrame(employe treeview) with angular 17?
The ngx-org-chart library does not appear to be fully compatible with Angular Ivy, which has been the default rendering engine since Angular 9. As of the latest information, ngx-org-chart has not been updated recently, making it potentially incompatible with Angular 17. This could lead to errors such as the module not being recognized as an NgModule class​
                                                                                                                                                                      give me solution ?

